# How to collect the crafted item into inventory in unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, I want to make a mini game where the player can craft item from very fundamental item to very advanced item (e.g. from a piece of wood then craft it into a spear). Basically it is some sort of Crafty by Brackeys but I would like to make my own version of Crafty!

I have been following the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fbd-yTcMgY&t=336s
The crafting system is very simple to understand. I also finished a inventory system that can store the material but now I am facing a problem is that I cannot collect the crafted item from the Result Slot. Does anyone know code the coding in the video so that I able to collect the item from Result Slot into my inventory?

Code is posted as below.
Thank you in advances

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CraftingManager : MonoBehaviour
{
private Item currentItem;
public Image customCursor;

public Slot[] craftingSlots;

public List<Item> itemList;
public string[] recipes;
public Item[] recipeResults;
public Slot resultSlot;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if(currentItem != null)
        {
            customCursor.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Slot nearestSlot = null;
            float shortestDistance = float.MaxValue;

            foreach(Slot slot in craftingSlots)
            {
               float dist = Vector2.Distance(Input.mousePosition, slot.transform.position);

                if (dist < shortestDistance)
                {
                    shortestDistance = dist;
                    nearestSlot = slot;
                }
            }

            nearestSlot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            nearestSlot.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = currentItem.GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
            nearestSlot.item = currentItem;
            itemList[nearestSlot.index] = currentItem;

            currentItem = null;

            CheckForCreatedRecipes();
        }
    }
}

public void OnClickSlot(Slot slot)
{
    slot.item = null;
    itemList[slot.index] = null;
    slot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    CheckForCreatedRecipes();
}

public void OuMouseDownItem(Item item)
{
    if (currentItem == null)
    {
        currentItem = item;
        customCursor.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        customCursor.sprite = currentItem.GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
    }
}

void CheckForCreatedRecipes()
{
    resultSlot.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    resultSlot.item = null;

    string currentRecipeString = "";
    foreach(Item item in itemList){
        if(item != null)
        {
            currentRecipeString += item.itemName;
        }
        else
        {
            currentRecipeString += "null";
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < recipes.Length; i++)
    {
        if(recipes[i] == currentRecipeString)
        {
            resultSlot.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            resultSlot.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = recipeResults[i].GetComponent<Image>().sprite;
            resultSlot.item = recipeResults[i];
        }
    }

}



}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you are going to need to provide the code from your attempts to do so and explain how the results you get are different from what you want. Nobody is going to be able to help if you ask a question as opened ended as this im afraid :)

Comment: Oops sorry for that I am actually new to this. I thought providing the hints of following the tutorial on youtube is enough. Here is the code by the way